# Not showing euro symbol

Tags: twig

I have a string that displays in the browser like that

EURO (&EURO;)

The way I am printing it from twig is

```
{{ country.display }}
```

I want to print the € as an euro symbol.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ country.display }}
{{ country.symbol | raw }}
```

I have created a lonely variable for the symbol and now I can apply "raw" filter and it works.